# Hide vim cmdline

Tags: vim

I know this is a little OCD, but now that I've tricked out my vim and tmux configs, I'm curious if it's possible to collapse the empty vim cmdline when not in use. It just sits there taking up a precious line of vertical real-estate!

[image: Vim cmdline being a total space hog]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `:help cmdheight`:

```
'cmdheight' 'ch'        number  (default 1)
                        global
                        {not in Vi}
Number of screen lines to use for the command-line.  Helps avoiding
hit-enter prompts.
The value of this option is stored with the tab page, so that each tab
page can have a different value.
```

`set cmdheight` argument must be positive, so no, it's not possible to hide the cmdline.

Answer (score 0):

In [Vim 9.0.0114](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/f39cfb72629f3e7fefaf578a3faa2619cd0654f8) and [Neovim 0.8 (prerelease)](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases), `set cmdheight=0` hides the command line.

Answer (score 0):

But in [Vim 9.0.0340](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/a2a8973e51a0052bb52e43a2b22e7ecdecc32003) it was removed again.